# freezed constructor initialisers

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-freezed

I have model like this (simplified):

```
@immutable
class CountryModel {
  final String name;
  final String isoCode;
  final String assetPath;

  const CountryModel({
    required this.name,
    required this.isoCode,
  }) : assetPath = 'assets/countries/$isoCode.PNG';
}
```

now I decided to migrate to [freezed](https://pub.dev/packages/freezed)
but can't understand how to deal with fields like `assetPath`

I have a lot of models, whose initial values based on constructor parameters

my freezed model:

```
part 'country_model.freezed.dart';

@freezed
class CountryModel with _$CountryModel {

  const factory CountryModel({
    required String name,
    required String isoCode,
  }) = _CountryModel;
}

// : assetPath = 'assets/countries/$isoCode.PNG'
```

how to add assetPath field here?

so before migration to freezed if I create `CountryModel` like this

```
CountryModel(name: 'name', isoCode: 'XX');
```

`assetPath` value should be `'assets/countries/XX.PNG'`

Comment: How about assign the path or using default value by freezed.

Comment: it is  working here I think, let me share on answer and test it yourself and let me know

Answer (score 3):

seems like there is no constructor initialisers in freezed
so as an option I solved it in this way:

```
part 'country_model.freezed.dart';
part 'country_model.g.dart';

@freezed
class CountryModel with _$CountryModel {
  const CountryModel._();

  const factory CountryModel({
    required String name,
    required String isoCode,
  }) = _CountryModel;

  String get assetPath => 'assets/countries/$isoCode.PNG';
}
```

from my perspective this is not the best solution, I'd prefer to use constructor initialiser but not this time

Answer (score 2):

I've used `Default` value for `assetPath`.

```dart
import 'package:freezed_annotation/freezed_annotation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

part 'country_model.freezed.dart';
part 'country_model.g.dart';

@freezed
class CountryModel with _$CountryModel {
   factory CountryModel({
    required String name,
    required String isoCode,
    @Default("assets/countries/\$isoCode.PNG") String assetPath,
  }) = _CountryModel;

  factory CountryModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$CountryModelFromJson(json);
}
```

Comment: ok , and you can find more on [pub](https://pub.dev/packages/freezed)

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't work :/ it produces values like this `assets/countries/$id.png` instead of `assets/countries/US.png`

Comment: If you want to use default `US.png` pass it there, to modify it you can use `.copyWith`